# Objective-C Testing Frameworks

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, unit-testing, xcode

Are there any tools or plugins for XCode that can generate test cases for your apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about automatic generation, but you might look into [OCUnit](http://developer.apple.com/tools/unittest.html).

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Xcode 3, then OCUnit is build right in: [Apple OCUnit Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#featuredarticles/UnitTestingXcode3/)